# Somar valores JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, soma

Eu estou começando a mexer com JSON e JavaScript e tenho o seguinte AJAX:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'https://...',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'inpnomeRequisitante=' + 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        success: function (data) {
            var fluxosAndamento = "";
            var fluxosSolicitadosAnoCorrente = "";
            var valor = 0;
            $.each(data.success, function (i, item) {}});
```

Esse AJAX retorna os valores exatamente assim:

```
{
  "success": [
    {
     "fields": {
        "Valor": "22,33",
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "Valor": "146,33",
      }
    }
  ],
  "cache": false,
  "datasource": 2166,
  "runtime": 63,
  "bytes": 2369
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber como é possível somar todos os valores retornados do `data.success[i].fields.Valor`, como neste exemplo: `22,33 + 146,33 + VALOR XXXX` (se tiver mais valores)... E como posso dar replace da "`,`" para o "`.`" em cada um desses valores dentro do $each para que possam ser somados já que o Javascript não aceita "`10,00`" e sim "`10.00`".

Comment: Seu JSON não é válido. Tem certeza que ele é assim mesmo?

Comment: Sim, não coloquei aqui a um url e nem o data que estou passando. Porém, ele me retorna os dados exatamente como está ali:

"Valor": "146,33",
"Valor": "22,33",

Comment: Então, se é **exatamente** como está ali, não é um JSON válido, não tem como analisá-lo com JS. Parece que há um colchetes errado na linha 13 que, talvez, não deveria existir.

Comment: Perdão @AndersonCarlosWoss! Exatamente, esse colchetes não existe ali. Você saberia como pegar o valor de cada data.success[i].fields.Valor e somar eles em uma única variável?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta adicionando o JSON válido para que possamos te ajudar com mais facilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um simples laço de repetição `for`:

```js
const data = {
  success: [
    {
      cod: '158877',
      txt: '158877',
      fields: {
        Valor: '22,32',
        Resultado_Instância: 'Solicitação Encaminhada',
        Status: 'Em Andamento',
        Data_Inicio: '13/06/2019 17:22:11'
      }
    },
    {
      cod: '157744',
      txt: '157744',
      fields: {
        Valor: '146,32',
        Resultado_Instância: 'Solicitação Encaminhada',
        Status: 'Em Andamento',
        Data_Inicio: '12/06/2019 17:22:11'
      }
    }
  ],
  cache: false,
  datasource: 2166,
  runtime: 63,
  bytes: 2369
};

let sum = 0;

for (const item of data.success) {
  sum += parseFloat(item.fields.Valor.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.'));
}

console.log(sum);
```

No entanto, se você quiser ir para um caminho um pouco mais sofisticado, pode também usar abordagens que fazem uso do `reduce`:

```js
const data = {
  success: [
    {
      cod: '158877',
      txt: '158877',
      fields: {
        Valor: '22,32',
        Resultado_Instância: 'Solicitação Encaminhada',
        Status: 'Em Andamento',
        Data_Inicio: '13/06/2019 17:22:11'
      }
    },
    {
      cod: '157744',
      txt: '157744',
      fields: {
        Valor: '146,32',
        Resultado_Instância: 'Solicitação Encaminhada',
        Status: 'Em Andamento',
        Data_Inicio: '12/06/2019 17:22:11'
      }
    }
  ],
  cache: false,
  datasource: 2166,
  runtime: 63,
  bytes: 2369
};

const sum = data.success.reduce(
  (acc, current) =>
    acc + parseFloat(current.fields.Valor.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.')),
  0
);

console.log(sum)
```

#### Leitura recomendada:

- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Obrigado Luiz! Vou testar as funções que você me passou aqui!

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Luiz já atende sua questão, apenas vou deixar mais um exemplo de como pode ser feito utilizando [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const dados = {
  success: [
    {
      cod: "158877",
      txt: "158877",
      fields: {
        Valor: "22,33",
        Resultado_Instância: "Solicitação Encaminhada",
        Status: "Em Andamento",
        Data_Inicio: "13/06/2019 17:22:11"
      }
    },
    {
      cod: "157744",
      txt: "157744",
      fields: {
        Valor: "146,33",
        Resultado_Instância: "Solicitação Encaminhada",
        Status: "Em Andamento",
        Data_Inicio: "12/06/2019 17:22:11"
      }
    }
  ],
  cache: false,
  datasource: 2166,
  runtime: 63,
  bytes: 2369
};
 
let valores = [];       // array para armazenar os valores pegos com um map()
  
dados.success.map(x => {
  valores.push(x.fields.Valor);
})
  
console.log(valores);
  
let soma = valores.reduce((a, b) => {       // método que faz a soma
  return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);     // converte de string para number
})
  
console.log(soma.toFixed(2));    // deixa com apenas 2 casas decimais
```

Comment: Show! Vou estudar um pouco mais sobre reduce! Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tens de tratar essa String para poder ser convertida em Number, depois tens de somar os valores.

Um exemplo seria:

```js
const dados = {
  success: [{
      cod: "158877",
      txt: "158877",
      fields: {
        Valor: "22,33",
        Resultado_Instância: "Solicitação Encaminhada",
        Status: "Em Andamento",
        Data_Inicio: "13/06/2019 17:22:11"
      }
    },
    {
      cod: "157744",
      txt: "157744",
      fields: {
        Valor: "146,33",
        Resultado_Instância: "Solicitação Encaminhada",
        Status: "Em Andamento",
        Data_Inicio: "12/06/2019 17:22:11"
      }
    }
  ],
  cache: false,
  datasource: 2166,
  runtime: 63,
  bytes: 2369
};

const values = dados.success.map(obj => {
  const valueString = obj.fields.Valor.replace(/,/, '.');
  return Number(valueString);
});
const sum = values.reduce((total, nr) => total + nr, 0);


console.log(sum.toFixed(2)); // 168.66
```